# Slope Standard Error c#

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Is there a function inside MathNet.Numerics to calculate regression slope error?

```
        double[] xdata = new double[] { 10, 20, 30 };
        double[] ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25 };

        Tuple<double, double> p = MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Line(xdata, ydata);
        double a = p.Item1; // == 10; intercept
        double b = p.Item2; // == 0.5; slope
```

The above gives the slope. How does one get the error of the slope?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`GoodnessOfFit`](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/GoodnessOfFit.htm) class has `R` and `RSquared` methods on it

An [example of usage](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Regression.html) taken from the website

```
GoodnessOfFit.RSquared(xdata.Select(x => a+b*x), ydata); // == 1.0
```

Your sample code comes from the same page.